# Google Earth Balloon Reload - Client and Plugin

Tags: javascript, html, reload, google-earth, google-earth-plugin

A bit of an aside before I get to my actual question:

A few months ago, I faced a problem where I needed to resize the Google Earth Balloon dynamically through javascript as I received AJAX calls (about twice a minute).  Sometimes each call would only require increasing the balloon by one or two pixels, which was not a huge issue.  The main problem was that some (a lot) of the time, the data I was getting back would require the balloon to be much larger which caused scrollbars to appear (an undesirable effect for the company I work for).  Eventually after throwing code at it for days, I found a pretty hacky way to get the balloon to resize just the way I wanted it.  After getting my data and refilling the balloon with the new data, I would call this:

```
setTimeout(window.location.reload, 250);
```

I had a theory that this would work since within the Google Earth application (Client and Plugin versions), I could right-click the balloon and click "Reload" and the balloon resized it the way I wanted it to.  Obviously there is something a bit fishy about this hack considering if I use the same code in a normal browser, the page would just reload infinitely, so I also had to figure out a way to determine if I was in Google Bubble or in a browser version of this webpage (which I found a way, but it's not important or relevant to my question that I am eventually getting to).  Now that things are a little less chaotic around the office, I want to find out EXACTLY why this works.

Finally, my question is: does the Google Earth API redefine the Window or Location Objects, or does it just redefine how window.location.reload works?

I am using Google Earth Client v6.1.0.5001 and Google Earth Plugin v6.2.2.6613

Answer (score 0):

> does the Google Earth API redefine the Window or Location Objects, or
>   does it just redefine how window.location.reload works?

No it doesn't redefine anything, it is just the plugin inside a frame on the page. Basically if you are within a frame [window](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window) refers to the current frame, [parent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.parent?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/window.parent#Summary) refers to the parent of the current frame and [top](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.top) refers to the topmost window in the window hierarchy.

When you first load the plugin you usually point the `createInstance` method at a `div` or other element on the page. e.g.

```
<div id='map3d'></div>
```

However, once the plugin has loaded if you look at the mark-up of the page you can see the plugin injects an iframe into that element. So you have something like...

```
<div id='map3d' style='...'>
  <div style='...'>
    <div style='...'>
      <iframe src="http://www.google.com/earth/plugin/..">
        <html>
          ...
```

So when you are referencing the `window` object you are referring to that frame, not the parent window.

Try calling `window.top.location.reload();` and `window.location.reload();` To show the difference.

> Obviously there is something a bit fishy about this hack

There is nothing fishy going on at all it is basic mark up. All you are doing is simply telling the current `frame` rather the topmost `window` to reload.

Comment: I'm still a bit confused though.  If you are familiar with the dojo library, there's a button that you can press on the page within the balloon that will perform dojo's flip animation and provide the user with entirely different data (a different REST call than used before).  After this new data is printed, I call the window.location.reload() function again.  Shouldn't the balloon therefore reload the page to it's previous state (before the flip) instead of just resizing itself?

Comment: You don't show any code at all it is impossible to say what should actually be happening.In general though `window.location.reload()` simply reloads the frame it is called from. You talk about 'dojo' and 'REST' calls - but you didn't mention any of that in the question. it sounds like you may even have extra frames inside the balloons themselves. Perhaps rewrite the question and actually show the code that isn't behaving like you think it should. In any case I think I answered your original question clearly -  it doesn't redefine anything, including how window.location.reload works.